# Visual Studio| installation file could not be downloaded

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to download Visual studio 2019. I have a trouble. In this picture says in English, installation file could not be downloaded.Download failed after nine attempts. I had just downloaded visual studio 2022,it failed too.I have not internet connection problem. How can I fix it?

[image: Visual Studio Error ss]

Comment: Just because you haven't got any internet connectivity issues doesn't mean the CDN hosting these files is necessarily working properly. Not sure why you want both VS 2019 and VS 2022 though!

Comment: No Firstly I wanted to download visual studio 2022 but It failed. After that I realized that I can't download I decided to download visual studio 2019. So it happens because of internet connection problems right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Do you have enough available disk space for the download and the installation?

Comment: I have 30GB free disk space. in SSD.I guess It is enough right?. Actually I tried to download HDD. It didnt fail. I have 800gb free space in HDD. But I want to download in SSD for working fast

Comment: Should be plenty of space. It is possible that the CDN is failing or a something is actively blocking the connection between yourself and the CDN.

Comment: I will try to free up more space. Thanks for answering!